# django admin specific redirects

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-admin

I have a Django website where all urls are pointed to admin like this :

**urls.py** (Root)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I would like to know how to make specific redirects from one url to another, as I only have one model to manage and one app:

> localhost/ => localhost/app/computer

> localhost/app/ => localhost/app/computer

I tried adding this to urls.py but it does not work :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

path('/', lambda request: HttpResponseRedirect('/app/computer/'))
```

I also thought of adding `urls.py` to app, but I think there might be a conflict as `path('')` will be on both `urls.py`, the root and the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement this by using a custom `RedirectMiddleware`

**settings.py**

```
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'app.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]
...
ROUTES = [
    {'source': '/', 'destination': '/app/computer/'},
    {'source': '/app/', 'destination': '/app/computer/'}
]
```

**middleware.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def RedirectMiddleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        path = request.path
        for route in settings.ROUTES:
            source = route['source']
            destination = route['destination']
            if path == source:
                return redirect(destination)
        return response

    return middleware
```

Not the best for sure, but it works for now, and any better suggestions will be greatly appreciated.